# Many similar ViewModel methods to fetch and prepare model data

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, active-directory

I have a MVVM application that fetches data from active directory and displays it in a `DataGrid`. The exact data displayed is determined by which query a user runs, and there are multiple available queries. Each query requires slightly different logic, but they all have the same general idea. These methods are all in my `ViewModel`. `Data` is a property that is bound to the `DataGrid` in the `View`.

If you would like to see any additional code for this review, please let me know. I am attempting to divide this project (several thousand lines long) into reasonably sized chunks for review. These methods are contributing greatly to the length, especially considering I intend on adding even more query options in the future. As of now, the whole class is 1000 lines long, with these methods being close to 400 lines.

```
private async void GetComputerGroupsCommandExecute()
{
    StartTask();
    QueryType = QueryType.ContextualComputerGroups;
    await Task.Run(() =>
    {
        var computerPrincipal = ComputerPrincipal.FindByIdentity(
            _principalContext, GetSelectedComputerDistinguishedName());
        _dataPreparer = new DataPreparer
        {
            Data = new[]
            {
                ActiveDirectorySearcher.GetComputerGroups(
                    computerPrincipal)
            },
            Attributes = DefaultComputerGroupsAttributes.ToList()
        };
        try
        {
            Data = new List<ExpandoObject>(_dataPreparer.GetResults())
                .ToDataTable().AsDataView();
        }
        catch (ArgumentNullException)
        {
            ShowMessage(
                "No groups found for the selected computer.");
        }
    });
    FinishTask();
}

private async void GetDirectReportDirectReportsCommandExecute()
{
    StartTask();
    QueryType = QueryType.ContextualDirectReportDirectReports;
    await Task.Run(() =>
    {
        var directReportUserPrincipal = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(
            _principalContext,
            GetSelectedDirectReportDistinguishedName());
        _dataPreparer = new DataPreparer
        {
            Data = new[]
            {
                ActiveDirectorySearcher.GetUserDirectReports(
                    directReportUserPrincipal)
            },
            Attributes = DefaultUserDirectReportsAttributes.ToList()
        };
        try
        {
            Data = new List<ExpandoObject>(_dataPreparer.GetResults())
                .ToDataTable().AsDataView();
        }
        catch (ArgumentNullException)
        {
            ShowMessage(
                "No direct reports found for the selected user.");
        }
    });
    FinishTask();
}

private async void GetDirectReportGroupsCommandExecute()
{
    StartTask();
    QueryType = QueryType.ContextualDirectReportDirectReports;
    await Task.Run(() =>
    {
        var directReportUserPrincipal = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(
            _principalContext,
            GetSelectedDirectReportDistinguishedName());
        _dataPreparer = new DataPreparer
        {
            Data = new[]
            {
                ActiveDirectorySearcher.GetUserGroups(
                    directReportUserPrincipal)
            },
            Attributes = DefaultUserGroupsAttributes.ToList()
        };
        try
        {
            Data = new List<ExpandoObject>(_dataPreparer.GetResults())
                .ToDataTable().AsDataView();
        }
        catch (ArgumentNullException)
        {
            ShowMessage(
                "No groups found for the selected direct report.");
        }
    });
    FinishTask();
}

private async void GetGroupComputersCommandExecute()
{
    StartTask();
    QueryType = QueryType.ContextualGroupComputers;
    await Task.Run(() =>
    {
        var groupPrincipal = GroupPrincipal.FindByIdentity(
            _principalContext,
            GetSelectedGroupDistinguishedName());
        _dataPreparer = new DataPreparer
        {
            Data = new[]
            {
                ActiveDirectorySearcher.GetComputersFromGroup(
                    groupPrincipal)
            },
            Attributes = DefaultGroupComputersAttributes.ToList()
        };
        try
        {
            Data = new List<ExpandoObject>(_dataPreparer.GetResults())
                .ToDataTable().AsDataView();
        }
        catch (ArgumentNullException)
        {
            ShowMessage(
                "No groups found for the selected direct report.");
        }
    });
    FinishTask();
}

private async void GetGroupUsersDirectReportsCommandExecute()
{
    StartTask();
    QueryType = QueryType.ContextualGroupUsersDirectReports;
    await Task.Run(() =>
    {
        var groupPrincipal = GroupPrincipal.FindByIdentity(
            _principalContext,
            GetSelectedGroupDistinguishedName());
        _dataPreparer = new DataPreparer
        {
            Data = new[]
            {
                ActiveDirectorySearcher.GetUsersDirectReports(
                    groupPrincipal)
            },
            Attributes = DefaultGroupUsersDirectReportsAttributes
                .ToList()
        };
        try
        {
            Data = new List<ExpandoObject>(_dataPreparer.GetResults())
                .ToDataTable().AsDataView();
        }
        catch (ArgumentNullException)
        {
            ShowMessage(
                "No users and/or direct reports found in the selected group.");
        }
    });
    FinishTask();
}

private async void GetOuComputersCommandExecute()
{
    StartOuTask();
    QueryType = QueryType.OrganizationalUnitComputers;
    await Task.Run(() =>
    {
        _dataPreparer = new DataPreparer
        {
            Data = _activeDirectorySearcher.GetOuComputers(),
            Attributes = DefaultComputerAttributes.ToList()
        };
        try
        {
            Data = new List<ExpandoObject>(_dataPreparer.GetResults())
                .ToDataTable().AsDataView();
        }
        catch (ArgumentNullException)
        {
            ShowMessage("No computers found in selected OU.");
        }
    });
    FinishTask();
}

private async void GetOuGroupsCommandExecute()
{
    StartOuTask();
    QueryType = QueryType.OrganizationalUnitGroups;
    await Task.Run(() =>
    {
        _dataPreparer = new DataPreparer
        {
            Data = _activeDirectorySearcher.GetOuGroups(),
            Attributes = DefaultGroupAttributes.ToList()
        };
        try
        {
            Data = new List<ExpandoObject>(_dataPreparer.GetResults())
                .ToDataTable().AsDataView();
        }
        catch (ArgumentNullException)
        {
            ShowMessage("No groups found in selected OU.");
        }
    });
    FinishTask();
}

private async void GetOuUsersCommandExecute()
{
    StartOuTask();
    QueryType = QueryType.OrganizationalUnitUsers;
    await Task.Run(() =>
    {
        _dataPreparer = new DataPreparer
        {
            Data = _activeDirectorySearcher.GetOuUsers(),
            Attributes = DefaultUserAttributes.ToList()
        };
        try
        {
            Data = new List<ExpandoObject>(_dataPreparer.GetResults())
                .ToDataTable().AsDataView();
        }
        catch (ArgumentNullException)
        {
            ShowMessage("No users found in selected OU.");
        }
    });
    FinishTask();
}

private async void GetOuUsersDirectReportsCommandExecute()
{
    StartOuTask();
    QueryType = QueryType.OrganizationalUnitUsersDirectReports;
    await Task.Run(() =>
    {
        _dataPreparer = new DataPreparer
        {
            Data = _activeDirectorySearcher.GetOuUsersDirectReports(),
            Attributes = DefaultUserDirectReportsAttributes.ToList()
        };
        try
        {
            Data = new List<ExpandoObject>(_dataPreparer.GetResults())
                .ToDataTable().AsDataView();
        }
        catch (ArgumentNullException)
        {
            ShowMessage(
                "No users and/or direct reports found in selected OU.");
        }
    });
    FinishTask();
}

private async void GetOuUsersGroupsCommandExecute()
{
    StartOuTask();
    QueryType = QueryType.OrganizationalUnitUsersGroups;
    await Task.Run(() =>
    {
        _dataPreparer = new DataPreparer
        {
            Data = _activeDirectorySearcher.GetOuUsersGroups(),
            Attributes = DefaultUserGroupsAttributes.ToList()
        };
        try
        {
            Data = new List<ExpandoObject>(_dataPreparer.GetResults())
                .ToDataTable().AsDataView();
        }
        catch (ArgumentNullException)
        {
            ShowMessage(
                "No users and/or groups found in selected OU.");
        }
    });
    FinishTask();
}

private async void GetUserGroupsCommandExecute()
{
    StartTask();
    QueryType = QueryType.ContextualUserGroups;
    await Task.Run(() =>
    {
        var userPrincipal = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(
            _principalContext, GetSelectedUserDistinguishedName());
        _dataPreparer = new DataPreparer
        {
            Data = new[]
            {
                ActiveDirectorySearcher.GetUserGroups(
                    userPrincipal)
            },
            Attributes = DefaultUserGroupsAttributes.ToList()
        };
        try
        {
            Data = new List<ExpandoObject>(_dataPreparer.GetResults())
                .ToDataTable().AsDataView();
        }
        catch (ArgumentNullException)
        {
            ShowMessage(
                "No groups found for the selected user.");
        }
    });
    FinishTask();
}
```

The `StartTask`, `StartOuTask` and `FinishTask` methods are as follows:

```
private void StartOuTask()
{
    StartTask();
    _activeDirectorySearcher = new ActiveDirectorySearcher(
        CurrentScope);
}

private void StartTask()
{
    HideMessage();
    ViewIsEnabled = false;
    ProgressBarVisibility = Visibility.Visible;
}

private void FinishTask()
{
    ContextMenu = GenerateContextMenu();
    ProgressBarVisibility = Visibility.Hidden;
    ViewIsEnabled = true;
}
```

Comment: Oh, the copy&paste design pattern ;-)

Comment: That looks better than reviewing the  1000+ code altogether

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. The methods should return `Task` instead of `void`. Otherwise exception are shallowed. Alternative you could encapsulate the whole content of the method in a try catch block.

See also: [Asynchrone return types - Void Return Type](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/hh524395.aspx#Anchor_2)

2. Try to follow the [DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) principle.

For example the line:

```
new List<ExpandoObject>(_dataPreparer.GetResults()).ToDataTable().AsDataView();
```

may be extracted to a method:

```
private static IList<ExpandoObject> GetData(DataPreparer dataPreparer) { ... }
```

3. It seems that the instance variables `_dataPreparer`, `_activeDirectorySearcher` class variables are set / used from different methods. That increases the comlexity of the program flow. I would try to avoid such 'global writable states'.

---

The view model seems to be used as universal container with high coupling. In the medium term, I would try to move the logic of each method to a single class that is independent of the view model.

Comment: What do you mean by "exception are shallowed"? The `ShowMessage` method does what it is supposed to with the message.

Comment: I mean, that the exception is thrown silently (you are not notified about the exception). Sure, the code within the inner try/catch block is not affected, but there is some logic before the try that may trhow exceptions. See also the link I'll add to my answer.